# Problemas ao tentar salvar dados vindos do formulário

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc

Não estou conseguindo pela página HTML inserir o nome e salvar. Alguém poderia explicar o quê está acontecendo?

```
@Entity
public class Livro {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Autor> autor;


    @ManyToOne
    private Professor professor;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Meu controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/livros")
public class LivroController {


    @Autowired
    private Livros livros;

    @RequestMapping("/novo")
    public ModelAndView novo(){

    return new ModelAndView("Livro");
    }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView salvar(Livro livro){
    ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView("Livro");
    livros.save(livro);

    return mv;
}
```

Página HTML:

```
<section layout:fragment="conteudo01">
<form action="from-horizontal" method="POST" th:action="@{/livros/novo}" th:object="${livros}">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <h1 class="panel-tittle">Casastro de professor</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      <label for="nome" class="col-sm-1 contrl-label">Matricula:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
         <input type="text" class="from-control"   id="nome"  th:value="*{nome}"/>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Erro:

> Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating
>   SpringEL expression: "nome" (template: "Livro" - line 31, col 54)

não entendo esse erro.

Documentação do thymeleaf:

```
<input type="text" id="datePlanted" name="datePlanted" th:value="*{datePlanted}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não adicionou a atributo `name` como mencionado pelo @Isaias, outra forma de preencher as informações de um `input` é utilizando o `th:field`

Faça assim:

```
<section layout:fragment="conteudo01">
<form action="from-horizontal" method="POST" th:action="@{/livros/novo}" th:object="${livros}">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <h1 class="panel-tittle">Casastro de professor</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      <label for="nome" class="col-sm-1 contrl-label">Matricula:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
         <input type="text" class="from-control"  th:field="*{nome}"/>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

O Thymeleaf vai se encarregar de criar os atributos necessários com o campo informado, dessa forma não precisa se preocupar com os atributos `id`, `name` e `value`, serão criados automaticamente

Answer (score 1):

No seu HTML, tente inserir a tag `name`, segue exemplo:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
     <input type="text" class="from-control" id="nome" name="nome" th:value="*{nome}"/>
</div>
```

Outro detalhe, tente debugar na linha:

```
livros.save(livro);
```

E verifique se o objeto livro está com o nome preenchido.